# Job schedule entry could not be created. Status code: 500

Tags: apache-spark, ibm-cloud, data-science-experience, dsx

I have received the following error when trying to save a DSX Scheduled Job:

> Job schedule entry could not be created. Status code: 500

Screenshot of the error message:

[image]

I've tried about six times over the last few hours and have consistently received the above error message.

Debugging via the browser network inspection tool I can see:

```
{
  "code":"CDSX.N.1001",
  "message":"The service is not responding, try again later.",
  "description":"",
  "httpMethod":"POST",
  "url":"https://batch-schedule-prod.spark.bluemix.net:12100/schedules",
  "qs":"",
  "body":"While attempting to get Bluemix Token from BlueIDToken, unable to retrieve AccessToken, failed with status 400 Bad Request, message = {\"error\":\"invalid_grant\",\"error_description\":\"A redirect_uri can only be used by implicit or authorization_code grant types.\"} Entity: {\"error\":\"invalid_grant\",\"error_description\":\"A redirect_uri can only be used by implicit or authorization_code grant types.\"}",
  "statusCode":500,
  "duration":666,
  "expectedStatusCode":201
}
```

Comment: The issue is reproducible.
It is being investigated.

Comment: This has been resolved, can you please recheck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Charles comment, the functionality is working ok now.  I guess if this happens to another user some time in the future they should contact support.